# Mysql server won't start after changing bind-address

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, linode, digital-ocean

I have two dropplets at digitalocean, one is for http server and another is for database.

In mysql config `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` I have set `bind-address` to digitalocean private ip and everithing was working without the errors.

After server was rebooted, mysql failed to start. After I change `bind-address` to `127.0.0.1` it was working again, but my php app could not connect to the database.

Just to be clear, this kind of set up was working fine atfer server reboot.

Comment: Are you sure the private IP was the same after reboot?

Comment: No, it was automatically changed to 127.0.0.1

Comment: So I have changed it again, mysql failed to start, change back to localhost and it is working, except I have no access to database. This was a bug in old mysql versions, but I use mysql 8.0.25

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the localhost IP address and is not set by DHCP. Use `ip a` to  find out the IP that your server picked up on reboot.

Comment: Or you can set the bind-address to `0.0.0.0` to listen on all IPv4 interfaces.

Comment: I tried, but whatever ip I set except `127.0.0.1` it throws an error. It seems as a bug.